# Function in R produces a null vector

Tags: r, vector

```
Snapshot_ID_Tag<-NULL
CreateIDtag<- function(A,B){
  for (i in A:B)
  {
    ID<-append(Snapshot_ID_Tag,c(paste("AT0",i,)),after=length(Snapshot_ID_Tag))
  }}
```

I am currently using this code to produce a vector of ID's for an experiment. My output should be a list of ID's for the sample (e.g. if A is 1 and B is 9, the result should be ("AT01","AT02",....,"AT09")) however whenever I run this code it produces a null vector. I've made several adjustments that I assumed would correct the issue but with no avail.

If somebody has a suggestion to how to correct this then please share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A for loop is completely unnecessary here

```
CreateIDtag <- function(A,B){
    paste0("AT0",A:B)
}
CreateIDtag(1,9)
# [1] "AT01" "AT02" "AT03" "AT04" "AT05" "AT06" "AT07" "AT08" "AT09"
```

Your original function has several problems. You should not be using a function to modify a global variable. Plus your function doesn't actually return anything because a `for` loop doesn't have a return value. And your `ID` variable is basically being reassigned and not "growing" because `Snapshot_ID_Tag` remains NULL after each loop.